# jQuery slide down div - disappears when click on callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidedown

I have a bit of a problem. Have done some slide down in to div of a calendar, work nice, but after I click on the arrow to change the month, whole calendar disappears. And I can't open the calendar again.

Here is the working version: http://apartamentychlebiwino.eu/rezerwacja/booking-search.php?check_in=14/05/2018&check_out=15/05/2018&capacity=1&currency=PLN

This is my code:

```
 $('.caleran-header').click(function(){
     $('.caleran-calendars').slideDown(1000);
     $('.caleran-header-start').addClass('kalendarz-start');
 });
```

Comment: You need to provide more code. Can't exactly tell what is going on with the current code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calendar dissapears for this:

```
.caleran-calendars{
    display:none;
}
```

Maybe you have to show the calendar container, maybe you can try

```
$('.caleran-header').click(function(){
$('.caleran-calendars').slideDown(1000, function(){$(this).show()});
$('.caleran-header-start').addClass('kalendarz-start');
});
```

Comment: Guess i found a solution, thanks to your simple advise, i've changed the solid display:none to a js inline, when clicked it's updated by the slidedown. That will close the question for me... Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

That is because the inline property `display:block` is set on the currently showed month when we click on the header input `#caleran-header` and when we click on the prev or next months arrow it brings or slides in the new div for the new month range and the current is removed so the approach you have used to keep the calendar hidden in the start with `display:none` and that too using the `inline` calendar is not that good, you have to show the calendar every time either you change the months from the arrow or by clicking on the month name

By Month Name i mean these sections

[image]

it will not show you the calendar again, what your best bet is to call these two lines

in the event `ondraw [function]:` event which fires after redraws in calendar

```
onredraw: function(caleran){
    $('.caleran-calendars').slideDown(1000, function(){$(this).show()});
    $('.caleran-header-start').addClass('kalendarz-start');
}
```

Look here for [**`EVENTS`**](http://rettica.com/caleran/docs/readme.html#available-events)